# Error installing cocoapods on Catalina 10.15.2

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

I just start learning swift and found I can get a lot of libraries from cocoapods, so I start installing the cocoapods by running `sudo gem install cocoapods`, however I got the following error during the installation:

```
Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.1.6
Successfully installed i18n-0.9.5
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.6
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.7
Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.11.3
Successfully installed nap-1.1.0
Successfully installed fuzzy_match-2.0.4
Successfully installed httpclient-2.8.3
Successfully installed algoliasearch-1.27.2
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200527-3399-1uix5ob.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.12.2/gem_make.out
```

I am running macOS Catalina 10.15.2 with Xcode 10.3, not sure is that because of the masOS is outdated, if so is there any way that I can fix the installing issue without updating the macOS?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me after I erased Macintosh HD from **macOS Recovery > Disk Utility** and then reinstalled macOS Catalina from **macOS Recovery** too.

Now, I'm on **macOS Catalina 10.15.7** and this error happened when I ran `sudo gem install cocoapods`.

I'm not sure yet why, but installing cocoapods via Homebrew worked for me.

brew install cocoapods

```
brew install cocoapods
```

If you don't have Homebrew yet, run the following on your terminal:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```